# Error: Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui, closures, self

I've reviewed the other questions on this topic on SO (there are many) but none of them address this error pertaining to a `@State` . And I thought that this was the very problem that `@State` solved!

Here is the relevant code

```
 struct ViewA: View {
    @State private var startAnimation = false
    
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    
    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            
            startAnimation = true //<--- The error is on this line
        }
            
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: startAnimation ? 5.0 : 1.0 , height: startAnimation ? 5.0 : 1.0))
    }
}
```

There error is `Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`

Now reviewing the other SO questions related to this error lets me know that this error is related to *time delayed changes* ...

Comment: Why not use .onAppear() ?? ```.onAppear() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                    self.startAnimation = true
                }
            }```

Comment: Okay... now why does it work inside of .onAppear() and not init()??

Comment: init is for initializing your variable, not for change variable value on some time periods.

Comment: Correct, it's for initializing the struct. For every time the screen needs to be redrawn the current ViewA is discarded and a new struct is created, which then calls init to initialize itself. OnAppear should will be called the one time. Also maybe a more SwiftUI way to delay an animation may be: `withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.5).delay(1)) { startAnimation = true  }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with the @State property, but with the fact that you are using an @escaping closure. An escaping closure can cause a strong reference cycle if you use self inside the closure. See for a nice article explaining @escaping closures this [link](https://learnappmaking.com/escaping-closures-swift/).

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: there's no such thing as reference cycle for structs

Comment: Well John, are you sure that the Timer and the DispatchQueue are also structs? They are remnants of Objective-C.

Comment: Timer and DispatchQueue are not structs. The `ViewA: View` in the question is a struct.